# Rails Turbolinks with multiple layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have an application with 3 different layouts:
 - 2 are for protected areas for users and admins (say user and admin layout)
 - the other one is the usual application layout
The application layouts uses some google services (maps, fonts and analytics) whereas the other don't, so in application layout i have the scripts included and in the others not.

What happens is that when logging out from the protected areas and redirecting to home page, scripts are not called because of turbolinks.

What i've tried is:

- to put `data-no-turbolink` in the link that destroys user/admin session (but no way because that is not a direct link to the home page, but just a call to an action that makes the redirect)
- to put `data-no-turbolink` in the home body, but no way because i need the head to be reloaded, where the scripts are
- to create an `initPage` function that contains all the things to be done at `document.ready` when loading the home page, but as before, scrips are not reloaded so only things that do not require exeternal services are working.

The only solution i found is to put the unneeded scripts also in the other layouts.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain this sentence? "to put data-no-turbolink in the link that destroys user/admin session (but no way because that is not a direct link to the home page, but just a call to an action that makes the redirect)"

Comment: ok, i'll try to be clearer. The logout is done with a link like this `<%= link_to 'logout', destroy_admin_session_path, method: 'delete', class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>` which calls a method in the Admin::SessionController that destroys the session and redirects the admin to the home page (same for user). It is not a direct link to the home page, that's what i wanted to say.

Comment: I still don't understand. You have to put `data-no-turbolink` for links that lead to layout change (which is complicated by itself most probably). AFAIK destroy session by default has `data-no-turbolink` anyway.

Comment: that's what i read here https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks, my destroy_session method is a Devise helper, dunno if it has data-no-turbolink already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about trying to add the `data-no-turbolink` to the logout button like this:

```
<%=
  link_to 'logout',
          destroy_admin_session_path,
          method: 'delete',
          class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger',
          data: {no_turbolink: true}
%>
```

This should render to something like:

```
<a href="/admins/sign_out" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-method="delete" data-no-turbolink>logout</a>
```

Comment: Already tried this way (as mentioned above) but was not working. Retried and now it seems working....such a mistery. Thx anyway for making me try again :)